# How to Use a Single Public IP for Two Fiware Instances

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I have a Fiware account that allows me to create 3 instances and
gives only a public ip.

So I created an instance in the Fiware that runs the Orion Context Broker and associated a Public IP. I needed to create another instance that runs Cepheus. I just do not have a public ip to associate with Cepheus and make use of its API.

What can I do to use the same Public IP for the two instances created?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Post here: http://joseignaciocarretero.blogspot.com/2014/09/fiware-lab-only-one-single-ip-per-user.html

You could also use ssh to Forward ports, something like this:

```
ssh -f -N -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -L :<cepheus_port>:<your_second_vm>:<local_cepheus_port> localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

jicarretero,

From what I understand, this form is for using SSH via terminal. Only my instances are in the Fiware Cloud and I'm running tests with Orion and Cepheus using RESTClient to send the requests. The above procedure, does it?